# add background image in react with bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs

if there s someone who can help me to fix this problem.
i can t add a background image to the Navbar in react.js
i will be thankful if there s someone who can help me.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import './navbar.css';

    class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="logo">

      <div>
        <Navbar/>
      </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

<--Style--!>
.logo{

    background-image: url('./header.jpg');

}
```

Comment: Try adding a height / width as well.

Answer (score 5):

First you have to import the pic you want to  add

```
import LogoImage from './header.jpg';

var sectionStyle = {
   backgroundImage: `url(${LogoImage})`
}

 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div style={sectionStyle}>

      <div>
        <Navbar/>
      </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I hope this will give you an Idea on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement to add a search bar with a background image. We can use Sematic UI to achieve the requirement. Please refer the below code.

```
                <Form inline  >
                    <Form.Row className="align-items-center">
                        <Form.Control as="select" size="sm" custom>
                            <option>Location</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                        <FormControl id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Search for Restaurants or Cuisines" />
                        <Button type="submit" className="mb-2">
                            Submit
                    </Button>
                    </Form.Row>
                </Form>
            </div>
```

Add the below below in the App.css.

```
.contact-background-image {
  background-image: url("https://img.food.com/img/upload/editorial/PACKAGE-COMFORT-FOOD/2016-12-23%20-%20Lasagna%20all%20day/four-lasagnes-16.jpg");
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 100% 
}
```

The above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a separate css file and importing that, then referencing your class name using className=!

Comment: @user1434285 i did it before but the same problem

Answer (score -1):

You can't put style inside a react.js Component.
You can solve this issue in two ways

1. You can put it inside your navbar.css file
2. You can put it as react inline css like below

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import Navbar from './Navbar';
   import './navbar.css';
   import image from "./header.jpg";

   class App extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
       <div className="logo" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image}` }}>
        <div>
          <Navbar/>
        </div>
       </div>
     );
    }
   }
   export default App;
   ```

Comment: @khaliloosben you have to put the image inside url.