# How do I add a background image in React+bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

I have been trying to add a background image to my webpage. This is how I am currently trying to do it but it doesn't seem to work.

in my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import LandingPageImage from './Components/LandingPageImage';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Screen" >
        <NavBar/>
        <LandingPageImage/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in my App.css file:

```
.Screen {
 background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536514498073-50e69d39c6cf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80");
}
```

This doesnot seem to work. I was expecting to see the background image on the Screen div but nothing shows up.

Comment: You can debug this simply by checking in developers tools in chrome whether the assigned css class was correctly added in html or not.

Comment: hope it will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360835/10477567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. I am thinking your `<Navbar />` and `<LandingPageComponent />` cover the entire div with their own backgrounds hence you are not seeing it.

Try adding some text to the div to see if it is working properly.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import LandingPageImage from './Components/LandingPageImage';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Screen" >
        <NavBar/>
        <LandingPageImage/>
        Text to give additional height to div.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Oh my god, you are right. I feel so dumb. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad, I was a help!